# Как подставить значение из переменной что-бы получить элемент?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть следующий код:

```
var form = $('#directory-contact-form-create');
```

в этой переменной находится объект:

```
`<div id="modal"><form id="directory-contact-form-create">...</form></div>`
```

который далее используется как:

```
form.on('beforeSubmit', function() { ...})
```

Так все работает, но поскольку ID формы бывает разный то я могу найти ID формы по родительскому ID блока `div`, который всегда одинаков:

```
var form2 = $('#modal').find('form').attr('id');
//здесь переменная = текст (id формы)
```

Так вот, как мне подставить ID формы в переменную, чтобы получить объект?

т.е. чтобы:

```
var form = $('#directory-contact-form-create');
```

было равнозначно:

```
var form = $('#form2'); 
//здесь нужно получить объект зная id формы
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как мне подставить `id` формы в переменную, чтобы получить объект?

Что бы "получить" нужный элемент из атрибута достаточно:

```
const attr = $("#modal").find("form").attr("id") 
const form = $("#" + attr)
```

Comment: Вы мой спаситель :)

Answer (score 0):

Вы уверены, что вам обязательно нужно получать id? Может быть вам поможет просто использовать такой селектор?

```
$('#modal form');
```

Comment: Уверен, т.к. вместо "directory-contact-form-create" может быть любое другое имя имя, например "directory-update" и т.д.

Comment: @Jekson353 Если вы можете выбрать форму (получить объект формы) следующим образом: $('#modal form'), то зачем вам ее id?

Comment: Убрал лишний id из вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Из вашего вопроса выходит 2 решения:
`$('#modal').find('form')` - это и есть ваша форма.
Либо использовать простую конкатенацию строк:

```
var form = $('#modal').find('form');
// Или же
var form = $('#' + $('#modal').find('form').attr('id'));
```

Comment: Ваш ответ чем то отличается от существующих?

Comment: В общем-то ничем, но был написан, когда тут не было ответов и отправлен с нескольких попыток...